# Counting with PHP from a dynamictable

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm not an expert in PHP even though I've been working with some stuff, copying and pasting from here and there, well I want to ask something that I can not find and that I don't have the slightest idea on how to implement it.

For instance, at a table like this:

```
    +------+-----+
    |NAME  |BIRTH|
    +------+-----+
    |John  |1980 |
    |Carl  |1982 |
    |Alice |1990 |
    |June  |1994 |
    |Rob   |1998 |
    |Alice |1998 |
    |John  |2000 |
    |Alice |2001 |
    |Etc.  |     |
    +------+-----+
```

I do different queries, like these below (and I could keep doing queries with any combination of years):

1. `Select * from table where BIRTH between 1980 and 1990`
2. `Select * from table where BIRTH between 1980 and 2001`
3. `Select * from table where BIRTH between 1990 and 2001`

So I will get 3 different tables, and from those tables I need to count the different contents,
for instance, from the table obtained with the query1 I need to obtain:

```
   John = 1
   Carl = 1
   Alice = 1
```

from table of query2:

```
   John = 2
   Carl = 1
   Alice = 3
   June = 1
   Rob =1
```

from table of query3:

```
   Alice = 3
   John = 1
   Carl = 1
   June = 1
   Rob =1
```

And remember the big table has 700 records, so it could appear any new name, and I need to print out the result in the same way:

```
   Alice = 3
   John = 1
   NewName = 1
   June = 1
   Rob =1
```

My final goal is do percentages in relation to the obtained table, and not to the total of registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it in SQL, not in PHP :

```
select NAME, count(1)
from TABLE
where condition
group by NAME
```

This will produce the exact view you want. Names as first column, the count on the second.

Comment: Excelent, it worked out, a question about the output, how can I make that, at the table, instead of "COUNT(1)" I could have, for instance "Quantity"<br>and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can use column aliases like this : `select NAME, count(1) as Quantity`

Comment: I think my new question wasn't published, well, it was, if I can obtain percentages also, like:

   John = 1 - 33%
   Carl = 1 - 33%
   Alice = 1 - 33%    Taking as total the resulting table, not the whole one (the one with 700 records)